# what does it means: {embed:entry_id}?

Tags: embeds, entryid

I would like to know about the usage of `{embed:entry_id}`.

It is used in case an `entry_id` is inside an embedded template?

There are other usages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1:

In some cases {embed:entry_id} would be most useful by passing an entry_id from the parent template into the embeded one's entries tag pair entry_id parameter to just return the results of the given entry_id.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}
     Just the entry that was passed from the parent template.
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Example 2:

In some cases you might want to pass multiple entry_ids into the entry_id parameter. Some might use an channel loop to output #|#|#|#|# into the the {embed:entry_id} variable. That would display multiple entries in the child template.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel" entry_id="#|#|#|#|#"}
     Just the entry that was passed from the parent template.
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explication, it's exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, that is how you call up the value of a variable declared within an embed tag.  So for example, if in your "main" template, you insert an embedded template called sidebar:

```
{embed="embeds/sidebar" the_passed_value="hello"}
```

Then in the embedded template itself, you could have:

```
I would like to say {embed:the_passed_value}.
```

Which would render as:

```
I would like to say hello.
```

And so as you see, it is a way to declare a variable within the embed code, passing its value to the embedded template for use there.

Comment: Thanks for the explication, i was not used with embed.